# Generate typescript types depending on generic provided object

Tags: typescript

Try to extend an object with a key depending on the keys of the object provided. is it possible to get this typed?

here is my current code:

```
const getData = <T extends Record<string, any>>(initState: T) => {
  const temp: Record<string, any> = {}
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(initState)) {
    temp[key] = value
    temp['set' + ucFirst(key)] = (value: any) => null
  }
  return temp
}

const a = getData({ test: 'demo' });

a.setTest() // not working
```

Comment: The keywords you're looking for are key remapping, mapped types and template literal types

Comment: thank you, that was what i was looking for, i try to find the answer on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With mapped types and [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), you could describe the result your code produces like this:

```
const getData = <T extends Record<string, any>>(initState: T): T & { [K in keyof T as `set${Capitalize<K & string>}`]: (value: T[K]) => void } => {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL26kw)